# Will Mac application developed in latest XCode work in old OS-X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, version-control, xcode5

I have MacOS-X - 10.7 and Xcode - 4.6.2 and made a Mac application. The client side machine is also MacOS-X - 10.7. But in my mac application there was a small error with NSNumberFormatter which when I was changing, Xcode was crashing. So I edited the code in latest Xcode and OSX. And then I made the binary of it and run in MacOS-x - 10.7, its working fine. But the source code is no more opening in Xcode - 4.6.2. Its asking for the latest version of Xcode. My question is will the binary will work fine in older version of OS-X even if it is developed in latest Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of OS X which your application will run on is dictated by the **OS X Deployment Target** in the project settings. If that is set to support 10.7, then it doesn't matter which version of OS X you built it on: the built application will work on 10.7 and later.

This setting will also set the minimum allowed OS in the Info.plist, so people trying to run the build on earlier OSes will see an alert instead of the app just crashing.

More information on setting the deployment target and building for different OS versions with SDKs is available in the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

Comment: My machine (mac mini) and the client machine (iMac) are both in same environment. OS-X 10.7.5 and its not that it doesn't run at all. The application runs for some time. I can enter data to DB(sqlite) but after two three data entered it gives out the error could not load the nib. I also tried changing the localization settings. still no luck.

Comment: Can anyone answer please?

Comment: I don't think this nib loading error has anything to do with the version of Xcode you're using, or the version of the client OS. You should carefully examine the nib it's trying to load. Have you set the OS X Deployment Target as I described above?

Comment: I got it solved with the above solution given by you. I tried it again from start by setting the deployment targets and base SDK. Its now working. Thanks buddy